# Ubuntu not booting after update

Tags: 14.04, boot

I recently installed some updates on my ubuntu 14.04 LTS. After I restarted my laptop it directly started in windows 8.1 without asking from which partition to boot. the starting GRUB screen has also disappeared.

Comment: You should be able to bring up the GRUB menu by holding Shift during boot. Also, please add the contents of `/etc/default/grub` as an [edit] to your question.

Comment: You can try to boot with previous kernel using grub.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting from a ubuntu live CD or a USB. If you can boot Ubuntu from a live CD, try installing "Boot Repair" available in the software center. Start "Boot repair". It automatically repairs any errors with GRUB.